# erdös-graham conjecture for 2014 items

Tags: number-theory

Erdős–Graham problem is the problem of proving that, if the set $\{2, 3, 4, ...\}$ of integers greater than one is partitioned into finitely many subsets, then one of the subsets can be used to form an Egyptian fraction representation of unity. That is, for every $r > 0$, and every $r-$coloring of the integers greater than one, there is a finite monochromatic subset $S$ of these integers such that

$\displaystyle \sum_{n\in S}\frac{1}{n} = 1$.

Now can i choose $2014$ separate $n$ number from the set $S$ to get their fraction sum $1$

Answer (score 1):

Unsurprisingly, the answer is no, not in general.

Easy counterexample: Let $r=2$ and take $S_1=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid 2\leq n\leq 2014\}$ and $S_3=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid n\geq 2015\}$.

Then $S_1$ doesn't even have $2014$ elements, and for any set $T\subset S_2$ with $|T|=2014$, we have $$\sum_{k\in T}\frac{1}{k} < \frac{2014}{2015}<1.$$